# How to change sort order of symbols in Spacemacs lsp-treemacs?

Tags: emacs, clojure, spacemacs

I'm using Spacemacs with lsp-treemacs. How do I configure Spacemacs to change the default sort order of lsp-treemacs's list of symbols (functions) to be based on the symbol/function name in a code file?

[image]

Comment: M-x customize-group ret lsp-treemacs ret. There is a parameter named `Lsp Treemacs Symbols Sort Functions`. It should be set to `Name`. [source code](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-treemacs/blob/c54503bec3d7a17eb7b4d30e3ab2f7916a26124c/lsp-treemacs.el#L442)

Comment: @leetwinski Why not write this up as a proper answer?

Comment: @Thomas because i'm not sure it is enough to help. Maybe the `imenu` sorting function should also be tweaked (since the screenshot seems to show the imenu output).. cant check it now.

Comment: When I `M-x customize-group`, it doesn't list `lsp-treemacs` as an option.

Comment: @JduPreez then maybe you don't have lsp-treemacs ? it could be just `treemacs`. As far as i remember treemacs uses imenu to generate symbols. So you can try to customize-group imenu. I bet there is a parameter for sorting there.

Comment: @leetwinski there might indeed be something more to do as you suggest. I can customize `Lsp Treemacs Symbols Sort Functions`, but the sorting of tags (symbols) is still "by position". Files in treemacs are instead sorted correctly wrt `Treemacs Sorting`. Do you have any more suggestions? :)
I have this issue with python (pylsp as language server)